# two different declarations of android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i made a fragment class Fragment1  and when trying to call it from the main activity , it displays an error like this

```
Fragment1 don= new Fragment1();
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return don;
}
```

but when i do this it works perfectly

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return (new Fragment1());
}
```

can someone explain to me why is this happening ??

it displays this error message

```
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): Process: com.abdelhadi.dontcha, PID: 1282
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't      change tag of fragment EditorChoice{b4db6930 id=0x7f05003c android:switcher:2131034172:0}: was android:switcher:2131034172:0 now android:switcher:2131034172:1
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:398)
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
06-28 20:50:41.111: E/AndroidRuntime(1282):     at        android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
```

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin just added the errors .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have your fragment adapter getsize() returning a number bigger than 1 and in this way you are returning the same instance for all fragments which is not possible.

Comment: because as i said you cant use same instance of Fragement for multiple pages as it will have one ID. you must have have a new instance for every page.